# bounties_offered are not being returned correctly from /users/{ids}/reputation

Tags: bug, reputation, bounty

When querying the [/users/{ids}/reputation](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/reputation-on-users) API route, reputation changes for `bounties_offered` are not being returned correctly.

In [my own results](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/reputation-on-users#page=19&pagesize=100&ids=1288&filter=default&site=stackoverflow&run=true), I see a reputation object with a `reputation_change` value of 0 and a `vote_type` of "bounties_offered" on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/453935/compiling-processing-sketchs-from-the-commandline), although I didn't offer a bounty on that question. (I did win one for my answer.)

```
{
  "on_date": 1233082673,
  "reputation_change": 0,
  "vote_type": "bounties_offered",
  "post_type": "question",
  "post_id": 453935,
  "user_id": 1288
}
```

I also don't see any `bounties_offered` reputation changes in [Undo's results](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/reputation-on-users#page=1&pagesize=100&ids=1849664&filter=default&site=stackoverflow&run=true), but he did offer a bounty on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20434489/1288).