# Total reputation reported by the /users/{ids}/reputation route is low

Tags: bug, reputation

When querying the [/users/{ids}/reputation](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/reputation-on-users) API route, the total amount of reputation I get back from all reputation changes is much lower than my reputation reported on Stack Overflow.  Here's my reputation from all seven categories reported by the API:

- My answer was accepted: 5790
- I accepted an answer: 0 (incorrect and [already reported](https://stackapps.com/q/4555/9))
- Questions: 12171
- Answers: 106487
- Bounties: 325 (incorrect and also [already reported](https://stackapps.com/q/4556/7653))
- Spam: 0
- Suggested Edits: 0

That's a total of 124,773, but my reputation on Stack Overflow is 136,858 as of this writing. That's a difference of just over 12k reputation.

When I parse the results of the on-site [reputation report](https://stackoverflow.com/reputation), I get the following results:

- My answer was accepted: 6075
- I accepted an answer: 124
- Reputation from questions asked: 12405
- Reputation from answers: 118167
- Net reputation from bounties: 175
- Reputation lost due to spam flags: 0
- Reputation from suggested edits: 0
- Reputation lost by downvoting: -189
- Uncategorized reputation changes: 0

As you can see, all categories are close, except for reputation from answers, which is 11,680 points higher on the on-site reputation report, which accounts for nearly all of the total discrepancy.  Is reputation gained from answers being misreported by the API?

Comment: The subset of reputation events returned is *probably* exclusive of deleted items, which I think the on-site report faithfully includes where applicable. That might be the source of the discrepancy but I'd have to science it to see if that's a valid explanation.

Comment: @TimStone You might be on to something. I know I have a ton of answers on old deleted questions that probably were upvoted enough and stuck around long enough that the reputation was grandfathered.

Comment: Deleted Q rep is sometimes grandfathered?!  I missed that meta post, looking...  Anyway, your offered bounties were ignored.  Maybe the API is also computing rep cap too aggressively?

Comment: @BrockAdams Yes, if a post stays on the site for 60 days or more and has a score of 3 or higher when it's deleted, you get to keep the reputation. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/124805/1288